# Why does the t-SNE paper claim that "large clusters of points that are far apart interact in just the same way as individual points"?

Tags: t-distribution, tsne, cauchy-distribution

In the [original t-SNE paper](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/vandermaaten08a/vandermaaten08a.pdf), the authors explain the use of the t-distribution with one degree of freedom (i.e. Cauchy distribution) for the map points, $(1 + |y_i - y_j|^2)^{-1}$, as follows:

> ...[it] approaches an inverse square law for large pairwise distances in the low-dimensional map. This makes the map’s representation of joint probabilities (almost) invariant to changes in the scale of the map for map points that are far apart. It also means that **large clusters of points that are far apart interact in just the same way as individual points**, so the
> optimization operates in the same way at all but the finest scales.

I think I follow the first point about scale invariance (I think this would hold for any power law), but I don't understand what exactly is meant by the second point about large clusters of distant points interacting in the same way as individual points, or how this follows from the t-distribution?

Comment: Very good question. I think they mean an analogy with Newtonian mechanics where the force is proportional to $1/r^2$ and any body from far away exerts the same force as a point mass in its center of mass. But I think this would actually hold for any power law, so does not really single out the $1/r^2$ similarity. So unless I am missing something, this sentence is rather misleading.